# IndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: java

```
public void thisisnotworking()
{
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String cardA;
    String cardB;
    System.out.print("Enter Card: "); cardA=input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter Card "); cardB=input.nextLine();
   Card a = game.get(game.indexOf(cardA));
   Card b = game.get(game.indexOf(cardB));
```

This code is part of a method i've written. Basically the user inputs the card that is one of the cards in an array list and then another card. Currently I'm getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException error when I'm running this part of the code.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it?

Comment: What values are you using? What line is throwing the error (it is in your stacktrace)?

Comment: Please complete the full code or at least thelines where the variable game is defined/initilizated/modified. Also add the input that you are providing in command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing `game`, but seems like `cardA` and `cardB` are not in `game`, so `game.indexOf(cardA)` returns **-1** and `game.get(-1)` throws the exception.

Also, looking at your code, you search for `String` in `game`, and then takes an element from `game`, which is a `String` and assigns it to a `Card` object. You cannot cast from String to any other class than `Object`, since `String` is a [**final**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29#Final_classes) class.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set the cards into the game? If there is no code missing that might be it, you need to call

```
game.set(cardA); 
game.set(cardB);
```

before `game.get(...);`

Comment: The cards are put into the game arraylist by being removed from the deck arraylist and then put into the game arraylist by using a deal method. (The deck arraylist is read in from a file of 52 cards.) What this method is meant to do is allow the player to enter a card (two cards actually) and then the method searches through the game arraylist to find that card. Therefore the cards the using is entering should already be in the arraylist.

Comment: Well, then you really need to show us the game class, if you want us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
public void thisshouldwork()
{
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String cardA;
    String cardB;
    System.out.print("Enter Card: "); cardA=input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter Card "); cardB=input.nextLine();
    game.add(cardA);
    game.add(cardB);
    Card a = game.get(game.indexOf(cardA));
    Card b = game.get(game.indexOf(cardB));
```

The problem is you aren't adding cardA or cardB to game so `indexOf` returns -1 and `get` throws an `IndexOutOfBounds Exception`

Comment: But cardA should already be in the arraylist and the method should search for that card.

Answer (score 0):

You must cast the return value of the `readLine` method to an `Object`, and then call the `toString()` method:

```
cardA=((Object)in.readLine()).toString();
```